# Why do function pointers require a return type?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Why is the following valid

```
int (*func)(int);
```

instead of

```
(*func)(int);
```

Isn't the first statement redundant, particularly given that the return type is not used in the method signature?

Comment: What do you mean, "the return type is not used"?

Comment: Q: Why *wouldn't* you want a prototype to declare the return type ("int", "double", "char *", "void", etc)?  What could possibly be gained by *NOT* specifying a return type???  And yes, "the return type" is very *DEFINITELY* "used" ;)

Comment: @melpomene The signature of a method is determined only by function name,parameters and the order of parameters. So when I say "return type is not used" I am saying that the signature of a method is not determined by its return type.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "signature" and "method" in this context?

Comment: @paulsm4 I mean you would be able to write less code and do the same thing. Hence, avoiding "boilerplate code"

Comment: But I like getting the result of my function back, even when called via a function pointer.

Comment: I don't really see what function pointers have to do with it. Couldn't you ask the same thing about regular function declarations?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar the function should have a return type but why would a function pointer need to specify the return type of the function?

Comment: @duper21 Because doing `void* (*get_mem)(size_t) = malloc; void *my_mem = get_mem(42);` should get you the same thing that `malloc` returns in this case, and the compiler needs the knowledge that `get_mem` points to a function that returns `void*` in order to properly call it and get the return value back.

Comment: @mzimmers That sounds backwards.

Comment: @mzimmers You're wrong there

Comment: Basically, C still performs type checking of the return value when it gets assigned to a variable. You could ask why you couldn't just declare your function pointer as returning `void` and allow it to accept any function with the same parameter signature, but that's a different question than what you asked...

Comment: melpomene, and M.M: thanks for spotting my error. I've deleted the comment. This surprised me: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs202.f15/Lectures/modules/m04-overload/slides.php?print

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate calls to a function, the compiler has to know the return type. This is true regardless of whether the call is made directly or through a function pointer.

For a practical example, consider the x86 platform:

- `int` values are returned in the `eax` register, so the compiler has to generate code to fetch the return value from there.
- `double` values are returned on the floating-point stack, so the compiler has to generate code to fetch the return value from there.
- `struct` values are not returned at all; the function takes an implicit output parameter (a struct pointer). The compiler has to generate code to reserve space on the stack and pass its address to the function.

If the compiler didn't know the return type, it couldn't compile calls to the function.

Comment: This is correct but circular. If the language didn't require the type to be known, then implementations couldn't use calling conventions that depended on the type without also conveying the type in some manner and emitting code to handle the returned value differently depending on the type conveyed (something akin to C++ RTTI). The fact that implementations *can* and *do* use efficient calling conventions is a consequence of type being statically known, not the cause of it.

Comment: @R.. That sounds backwards to me. Implementations came first; the language was standardized later.

Comment: The language existed in nonstandardized form before there was a standard. My comment about circularity isn't so much about a standard as about the concepts of the language, which were of course partly motivated by the implementation constraints they would produce, and admitting a thin implementation.

Comment: Note there could just as easily have been a conversion from `T(*)(Args...)` to `void(*)(Args...)` (Or a special "return value is unused" function pointer type). This is just not in the C language (because no one would use it often enough, and you can simply create a wrapper that returns `void`), so it's not really correct to say that the return type has to be known.

Answer (score 4):

Your claim

> particularly given that the return type is not used in the method signature

is simply wrong. The return type of a function is absolutely part of its "signature", and is even more important/essential than the argument types, not less. It's still valid C to have non-prototype function declarations or function pointer types as long as you follow certain rules about the types of the expressions you pass, but it's never valid to have a function declaration/type without a return type. This is because the type of the expression resulting from the function call cannot be inferred from anything else; it comes entirely from the type of the called function.

Comment: So because the return type is part of the method signature, the function pointer must also contain the return type.

Comment: In the C++ standard the term "signature" for a non-template function excludes the return type,  this might be the basis for OP's choice of terminology

Answer (score 1):

A function pointer must have a return type because the **function-call operator** `(...)` works **only with function pointers**, and the function-call operator must know the type of value returned by the pointed-to function. So in fact, when you write `sqrt(256.0)`, the function `sqrt` is implicitly converted to a pointer-to-function of type `double (*)(double)` and then the function call operator is applied to *this pointer*.

---

Remember that it is legal to write

```
int my_root = sqrt(256.0);
```

even though `sqrt` returns a *`double`*. The compiler cannot infer the type of the value returned by any other means, much like you cannot infer from a `void *` what type of value it is pointing to, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about registers and stacks and other implementation details.  It’s simply a matter of how C’s type system is defined.  Is it possible to declare a simple pointer without a type, *a la*

```
*p;
```

No, it’s not - the *declarator* `*p` only specifies that `p` is a pointer to *something*, but you have to specify what that something *is*:

```
T *p;
```

The type of `p` is “pointer to `T`”, for some arbitrary type `T`”.  Now, let’s suppose `T` is a typedef name for a function type:

```
typedef int T( int );
```

A function type *must* have a return type (even if older versions of the language defaulted to `int` if the return type wasn’t explicitly specified, the return type is an integral part of a function type).

So, if you have a pointer to a function type, the return type of the pointed-to function is a part of that pointer type as well.  And that is why your function pointer is declared as

```
int (*func)(int);
```